# how to use animation with AOS on pseudo element?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

Normally in HTML file I use AOS like this

```
<li data-aos="fade-left" class="fields__box">
```

I try in different way use AOS with pseudo element in my CSS file but I don't do this in the right. 
Do you have some idea how can I do that?
Thanks for your help

```
 &::before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;        
        background-image: url(images/logoBig.png);
        z-index: -1;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 70%;
        background-position: center bottom;
        // data-aos="fade-up";
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used Animate on Scroll (AOS) before, but based on a reading of the [docs](https://github.com/michalsnik/aos/tree/v2) and [CSS Tricks post](https://css-tricks.com/aos-css-driven-scroll-animation-library/), I think it can be done.

Here's what AOS is doing, JavaScript-wise:

> The idea behind AOS is straightforward: watch all elements and their positions based on settings you provide them. Then add/remove the class `aos-animate`. Of course, in practice, it’s not always that easy, but the idea behind AOS is as simple as that. Every aspect of animation is handled by CSS.

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/michalsnik/aos/blob/v2/src/sass/_animations.scss) for the `fade-up` animation, you could try:

```html
<li data-aos="fade-before-up" class="fields__box">
```

```
&::before {
    /* ... your properties to style the before element ... */
    transition-property: opacity, transform;
    opacity: 0    
    transform: translate3d(0, 100px, 0);
}

&.aos-animate::before {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Key points:

- I haven't tested this. Sorry. If you'd like to create a CodePen or a JSFiddle that replicates the current behavior you're seeing, I'll see if I can tweak it.
- The `data-aos` attribute on the HTML element shouldn't match an actual AOS animation. It's just to get the library to put the `aos-animate` class on the element.
- The `::before` pseudo-element is initially styled as 0 opacity and 100px below. When AOS adds the `aos-animate` class to the `<li>`, then the `::before` element can be transitioned.